# Remove comma as number grouping symbol

Tags: regex, vim

I have list of numbers like

```
990.00
2,940.00
4,500.00
600.00
```

I need to remove `,` from those strings.

So far to find desired cases I use `\d,\d\d\d\.\d\d` but I stack with replacing expression.

Comment: Are you trying to replace it, or just remove it?

Comment: to remove is enough for me

Comment: If these are just independent strings, a simple find: `,+` and replace `''` will do it. Are there any specific form requirements? Like only after 3 digits.. where `,,0,0.1` no comma's are removed?

Comment: @sln commas also present in another places not only as grouping symbol. Seems like comma delimits each 3 digits as usual `1,000.00 100,000.00` etc.

Comment: @triclosan - If it is true that comma's are in other places too, then `,\d{3}` alone is _NOT_ sufficient. The entire number must be validated, from start to end, before the comma's can be removed. Otherwise using `,+` is the same as a `,\d{3}` partial validation, i.e. each could be error prone.

Comment: @sln sure, but in my case max value is 14000 thus only one comma. Sorry for misleading in my previous comment.

Comment: @triclosan - Don't know the context, all I see is your sample list. What happens when you replace on just comma, with no regex?

Answer (score 2):

You can find `,(\d{3})` and replace with capture group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what other strings you have present, I think tenub has the easiest solution.

If you're going to do that in vim, you'll need to use something along these lines:

```
%s /\,\(\d\{3}\)/\1/
```

`%s` - replace all occurances

`\1` - First capture group

Other characters escaped as required.

Although I'm an vim amateur, so there may be a simpler way.

Comment: Don't sell your self short, this is an nice substitution. You can of course golf it a bit. The first way is to use `\v` to reduce the escaping: `%s/\v,(\d{3})/\1/g`. The other option is to use `\ze` to get rid of the capture group completely: `%s/,\ze\d\{3}//g`. To learn more see `: h /\v` and `:h /\zs`

Comment: Ta for the hints! It's tips like this that keep inspiring me to chisel away at the vast store of vim functionality =D

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions posted so far use *capture groups*, but for a simple replacement / deletion, this isn't necessary. Just assert what has to come before / after the comma (to avoid removing it in unwanted places), and restrict the match to the comma itself via the `\zs` (start match) and `\ze` (end match) special atoms:

```
:%s/\d\zs,\ze\d\d\d\.\d\d//g
```